# Understanding Orgmode Properties for Org-babel?

Tags: r, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

My understanding of the property syntax for org-babel/orgmode is that by using the `header-args:R` I should be able to set up "options" for all R src blocks in an org file. This will work if I declare them on the line in the `BEGIN_SRC`, but I don't want to type the same options over and over, and I would like to do it for the whole buffer. Using org-version 8.3(Beta)

Questions: I have misunderstood the syntax, or is there likely something wrong with my install?

```
#+TITLE: Test
#+DATE: 
#+AUTHOR:
#+EMAIL: britt
#+LANGUAGE: en
#+SELECT_TAGS: export
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R  :session *R2*

* Introduction

Want to get buffer property to work

#+BEGIN_SRC R
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: After having set the property at the buffer level don't forget to refresh with C-c C-c with the cursor on the property.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the column in front of `session`...

PS- You can find such info in my (incomplete, not up-to-date as I would like) Org Babel Refcard at https://github.com/fniessen/refcard-org-babel.

Comment: I had already found your page, and use it often. I went back to your page and found my problem. It is not an extra column (or colon), but rather that I was not doing C-c C-c on my Property line to reset the local properties. I knew I had to do that in the source block, but did not realize that the Property were also "code" so to speak, I thought it was just some sort of text look up. So I can't mark you as having answered my question, but I can give you a vote up for the reference card, which did lead me to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed with your POV. And you're fully right, what I wrote is plain wrong... Sorry. Thanks anyway for the vote!

Comment: Note that I do have a function, bound on F9, which does the `C-c C-c` stuff and much more (realign tags, recompute tables, etc.) when exporting to HTML and/or to PDF. See function `org-save-buffer-and-do-related` in https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven/blob/master/emacs-leuven.el.